# Why is String[] args not initialized for it to be used like other String Arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, string, command-line-arguments

I'm learning Java and I was wondering, how String args[](`main`'s argument) works. For other string arrays defined in a method, they need to be initialized with a fixed dimension for them to be used.

For example,For entering 10 or less elements in a string, I need to type `String a = new String[10];`

However, if  I just  type `String a;` and then type `a[0] = "Word;"`, I get a "*variable a might not have been initialized*" error.

However, for String args[], I don't need to type `String[] args = new args[]`. Why is it so? Also, is it possible to create a string with infinite size like String args[]? (Sorry if I wasn't clear)

Comment: The parameter of the main function is not initialized by you, but the vm when creating your applications thread. From your perspective, you get an array reference just as if you'd call a arbitrary function which takes an string array as an argument. 
Furthermore, no java array may have infinite size. Even the main functions string array parameter has the same upper bound as any array in java. It should be 2^31-1, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: The difference is you expect the calling code to create the array instead of having to create the yourself.  When it is created, it is the same way.

Answer (score 4):

> For other string arrays defined in a method, they need to be initialized with a fixed dimension for them to be used.

Well, that is what happens in case of `String...` argument of the `main` method. It gets initialized with the fixed number of arguments you pass as command line args. But after that, you can't add anything to the array, as the size is now fixed. If you don't pass any argument, it's length will be `0`.

Note that the argument type is actually a varargs, and not a `String[]`, although, internally the former is converted to the later anyways. The benefit you get with varargs is, you can pass variable number of arguments without explicitly creating an array.

> Also, is it possible to create a string with infinite size like String args[]?

No the size of array is not unlimited. Since the type of `args.length` is an `int`. The maximum number of elements logically can be `2 ^ 32 - 1`. But actually it's not even that. Memory would probably overflow much before than that.

Also note that, since we are talking about method formal parameter, there is still a restriction of maximum method size. As per JVM, the maximum size of method is restricted to 65536 bytes.

**For Example:**

```
public static void test(String... names) {
    System.out.println("Names array length: " + names.length); 
    names[names.length] = "xyz";  // This would fail as expected.

    names = new String[10];   // this however you can do. Re-assign a new array to names 
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    test("a", "b", "c");  // pass 3 arguments
    test("a", "b");       // pass 2 arguments
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's only an information, that the parameter is of type `String[]`, so it's a table of Strings. 
It is a type, not any kind of initialization.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM is setting up the String[] argument for you prior to passing control to your main(), sort of like this:

```
class InternalThingYouDoNotSee {
    String[] args = build args[] from command line
    Class.forName("YourClass").newInstance().getDeclaredMethod("main").invoke(args);
}
class YourClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /....
    }
}
```